Dalton-Llewellyn method
I need to solve the discrete linear programming problem using the Dalton-Llewellyn method:
$$
L(x)=-x_1+4x_2+2x_4-x_5\to max,
$$
$$
x_1-5x_2+x_3=5,
$$
$$
-x_1+x_2+x_4=4,
$$
$$
x_1+x_2+8x_5=8,
$$
$$
x_j\ge 0, j=\overline{1,5},
$$
$$
x_1 \in \\{ 0;1.5;2.8;4 \\},
$$
$$
x_2 \in \\{ 0;1;3.5;6.4;8 \\},
$$
$$
x_3 \in \mathbb{Z},
$$
$$
x_4, x_5 \in \\{0,1\\}.
$$

What have you tried so far?

Have you solved using other methods ?

@SandeepTiwari I tried to solve this problem in Excel

@JeanMarie No, i tried only this method
